# batch file, creating numbering list

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file that stores log info, so let say you enter username and pass, it is encrypted and stored on a text file, that works great, the text is stored in this format:

```
xewiofjeoijfe

casowc43pcj89
```

And so on, i just used random text by the way on the above lines to use as example, so every new line of text is added to the bottom of the text file, what I'd like to do is that every time a new line is added, is added with a number or name and number, like so:

```
username1 fewfuhvruivhriuvew

username2 erwve9p8rvejp9

username3 vj39gew4tg000904t3[0g9i40
```

How can i accomplish this?

Comment: How can we expect to understand your question when you give different output in your two examples? Use your existing data for both the before _and_ after examples. Are the usernames already in the text file? Are you storing an actual username followed by the line number, or just the word "username?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what it is you want to do this should be close:

```
@echo off
set "LogFile=Test.txt"
if not exist "%LogFile%" type nul>"%LogFile%" & rem this line needed to create empty file if file does not exist
set "YourLoggedInfo=SomeInfoYouLogged" & rem this line will be replaced by what you are currently logging

rem below we will get number of existing lines and add 1
set /a LastLine=0
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in (`findstr /n . "%LogFile%"`) do set /a LastLineNum=%%a
set /a LastLineNum+=1
rem replace %YourLoggedInfo% in the line below with what you are currently logging
echo(Username%LastLineNum% %YourLoggedInfo% >>"%LogFile%"
```

Comment: sorry, @Ketan is right, i should of post some actual code:
`@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST Username.txt type nul > Username.txt
IF NOT EXIST  Keypass.txt type nul > Keypass.txt
:AdminReg
echo Register New Admin
set/p "Admin=Enter Admin Name : " 
set/p "Pass=Enter Password : "
IF ["%Admin%"] == [""] goto SIGNUPERROR
IF ["%Pass%"] ==[""] goto SIGNUPERROR
goto SAVENEWADMIN`

SAVENEWADMIN<<this menu i left out from showing,  due to irrelevance to the problem

Comment: `:CHECKUSERNAME
find /I  "%EncryptOutUsername%" Username.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (echo Username Exists! Try a Different One! && goto AdminReg)
goto savetofile
:savetofile
>>"Username.txt" echo(%EncryptOutUsername%
>>"keypass.txt" echo(%EncryptOutPass%
pause 
goto AdminReg` 

Sorry i had to post 2 comments due to comment character limit

Comment: I posted my answer before you posted code. Is there still a problem?

Comment: sorry i didnt reply to that, i plugged in the code, and for some reason the batch file is trying to find the command "findstr" on the text file, it says "The system cannot find the file findstr", i think is because it cant find the text file itself? i am using the file "Username.txt" with no path as im telling the batch file to write the text file where the batch is being executed from, meaning is making the text file on the same folder, by using:
`IF NOT EXIST Username.txt type nul > Username.txt
IF NOT EXIST  Keypass.txt type nul > Keypass.txt`

Comment: i think is because when i plugged in the code i didn't see the syntax of the "FOR LOOP" on the code you gave me, and the text file is written as a variable, but im logging the info on an actual .txt file, what is the difference from using

 "IF NOT EXIST Username.txt type nul > Username.txt"
vs
"if not exist "%LogFile%" type nul>"%LogFile%"

Comment: ok, so i modified the for loop, and it works! but, it still says "the file cannot find the file findstr", weird... so i modified the necessary variables, and now the portion of the code i needed looks like this: 
`set /a USERLastLine=0
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in (findstr /N "%EncryptOutUsername%"  Username.txt) do set /a USERLastLineNum=%%a
set /a USERLastLineNum+=1
echo(Username%USERLastLineNum% %EncryptOutUsername% >> Username.txt` 

it works great, just like i wanted, but like i said it still shows the error "the file cannot find the file findstr", syntax?

Comment: These comments get hard to read.There are several problems: 1. You are missing "num" in this line set /a USERLastLineNum=0  2. Use the "." in the findstr line as a wildcard to count ALL of the lines as I did above... not to just look for one line. findstr /N . Username.txt.

Comment: i know, wish there was text editing tools here... anyways, thx for pointing those things out, when i add the "" to the "findtstr" command line, it gets worse, it says "the system cannot find the file findstr /N "somevariablehere" Username.txt", i don't know if i need the dot after the "/N", but either with or without the dot "/N." it still shows the same error, it stores the variable like i want to, it works, but keeps showing that error

Comment: It is /N .   that is /N space period

Comment: ok, i think i found the right syntax, this is what i have: 
`for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N . "%EncryptOutPass%"  Keypass.txt') do set /a KEYLastLineNum=%%a`

the previous error of not findind the findstr text is gone, but i have a new error:
first problem when saving the variable to the text file, it doesn't count the line and adds them up with the number 1, like this:
user1 sdgvopkrs
user1 sfvnrmmm
user1 ggghythh

second problem, the batch file is displaying a "Divided by zero error"

Comment: OMG, i finally got the syntax right!, i was using the wrong character, it was ` not ', using ' forces the command to look for text, using ` is to run a command, also removed the %variable% from the command and just left the text file as in your example, so the command line looks like this: 

`for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=:" %%a in (`findstr /N . "Username.txt"`) do set /a USERLastLineNum=%%a`

it works like a charm! no errors, and i can close the batch, run it again, and it will keep adding the number on the list accordingly, thank you so much! you had it right from the first answer!